# how to convert arraylist to array in typescript

Tags: typescript

i'm working firebase cloud function. i have written script in typescript.after getting snapshot  and fetch some ids from snapshot i got array-list like.

> [[-LRosbC0OZyOUl5qs_Wc, -LRoztmKz6XJzDPicDq8], [-LRot-OCd9PJ73EGpOZx]]

now i want to convert this array-list to array like

> [-LRosbC0OZyOUl5qs_Wc, -LRoztmKz6XJzDPicDq8, -LRot-OCd9PJ73EGpOZx]

how can i achieve this

any suggestion is greatly appreciated Thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

Comment: There is no such thing as an array-list in typescript, what you seem to have is an array of arrays. Your array content doesn't look right though, I assume the content are strings?

Comment: as i m new in typescript so i said array-list sorry for that.but yes those values are string

Comment: Basically, the type is `string[][]` and you want `string[]`. You can use `flat` as @ritaj proposed, but it won't work in all browsers as it is a recent addition to javascript. The operation to go from `any[][]` to `any[]` is called flattening and there is a lot you can find about it online. Here's one way to do it https://schneidenbach.gitbooks.io/typescript-cookbook/functional-programming/flattening-array-of-arrays.html